# Capture same line multiple times

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

Given text like,

> A 0 1 2 3 4

I want to match the A with each number as a separate match like,

```
re.findall(some_regex, "A 0 1 2 3 4")
```

would return,

```
[
  ["A", "0"],
  ["A", "1"],
  ["A", "2"],
  ["A", "3"],
  ["A", "4"],
]
```

Comment: That's not possible. A regexp always matches a contiguous substring.

Comment: All regex engines by default, advance the current (search) position by 1 if it matched at the same point as the last match. You could do something tricky with a lookbehind, but it requires a fixed value progressing using alternations where the number of alternation is fixed with a corresponding number of capture groups. In PCRE you have a chance to filter the number of groups to 2, but the alternations stand. In Dot-net you can use a single lookbehind and no need for alternations `(?<^(.).*)(.)` walla ..

Answer (score 1):

```
    dd ='A01234'
    Result = [[dd[0],j] for i,j in enumerate(dd) if i!=0]
    #Output = [['A', '0'], ['A', '1'], ['A', '2'], ['A', '3'], ['A', '4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. But you can generate such a list easily.

```
x = re.findall("A*[0-9]", "A 0 1 2 3 4")
result = [["A", str(c)] for c in x]
```

Comment: So `(A).*?(\d)` will match [A, 0]. If you make the middle greedy you get the 4. Regex can't sort of just iterate from 0 to 4 in a non-greedy fashion?

Comment: Don't think it's possible. `(A)*(\d)` will get `[('', '0'), ('', '1'), ('', '2'), ('', '3'), ('', '4')]` which is really close.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I did it with two Python [`regex`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

```py
import re

text = "A 0 1 2 3 4"  # your text here

"""
select first character which belongs to alphabetically
between a and z, lower case OR upper case. If you need
to match only upper case character, just change pattern1
into "^[A-Z]"

pattern2 will match all the string contains with digits
which mean numbers from 0-9
"""
pattern1 = "^[A-Za-z]"
pattern2 = "\d"

print([[re.search(pattern1, text).group(0), a] for a in re.findall(pattern2, text)])
```

Output is,

```py
[['A', '0'], ['A', '1'], ['A', '2'], ['A', '3'], ['A', '4']]
```

Now you can change first character as you wish with any number of digits.